# Restrict direct access to pdf, but allow view through <object>

Tags: php, pdf, mod-rewrite, apache2, file-access

After googling I didn't find answer to my question.
So, question.
I have site with http://www.emathhelp.net
Inside it there is folder with pdf files.

I want to restrict direct access to pdf files, so http://www.emathhelp.net/1/3192849.pdf will return error, but a page with code
`<object data="pdf/1/3192849.pdf"></object>` will correctly fetch pdf.

One of the attempts was to redirect all urls that end with .pdf to php script which then will find the page where pdf is embedded and redirect there. It was done, however inside `<object></object>` there is black screen, because I guess `data="pdf/1/3192849.pdf"` is rewritten also an thus infinite loop is created.

Can you help me?
Maybe there are some solutions through .htaccess, maybe I don't need to use `<object>`.
Please, write your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it out of the web root folder. However, when it is supposed to be shown, use PHP to copy it to a temp location in your web root folder and display it to the user who is meant to see it. Keep a record of the temp file in a database, so that it is removed after say 1-2hrs.

Links:

- [Copy a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) in PHP
- PHP [PDO tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: I'm new to this. Where should I put it? Currently folder is at public_html/pdf

Comment: I guess public_html/ is the web root folder - is that where the index.php file is which is shown when someone visits yourdomain.com ? If you take it out of the public folder - it is offline therefore no one can access it.